# Agrupar um array e somar uma determinada chave

Tags: php, array

Olá, pessoal! Preciso agrupar array's que possuem algumas chaves iguais. Exemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103215122
            [codCliente] => 4519878
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => FEV
            [mes_entrega] => 02
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103215122
            [codCliente] => 4519878
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => FEV
            [mes_entrega] => 02
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103215122
            [codCliente] => 4519878
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => FEV
            [mes_entrega] => 02
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103215122
            [codCliente] => 4519878
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => FEV
            [mes_entrega] => 02
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )
     [4] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103217890
            [codCliente] => 4519900
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => MAR
            [mes_entrega] => 03
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )
)
```

Preciso agrupar os array's e somar a chave **qtde** dos array's que possuem a chave **CodProposta**, **mes_entrega** e **ano** iguais

O retorno que espero é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103215122
            [codCliente] => 4519878
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 4
            [mes] => FEV
            [mes_entrega] => 02
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [codProposta] => 20211103217890
            [codCliente] => 4519900
            [entrega] => A CONFIRMAR
            [qtde] => 1
            [mes] => MAR
            [mes_entrega] => 03
            [ano] => 2022
            [estoque] => PRODUCAO
            [status_e] => 1
            [status_obs_e] => 2
            [autorizado] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solucionei da seguinte forma:

```
function groupData($data)
{
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $key = $item['codProposta'].$item['mes_entrega'].$item['ano'];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $groups)) {
            $groups[$key] = array(
                'codProposta' => $item['codProposta'],
                'codCliente' => $item['codCliente'],
                'entrega' => $item['entrega'],
                'qtde' => 1,
                'mes' => $item['mes'],
                'mes_entrega' => $item['mes_entrega'],
                'ano' => $item['ano'],
                'estoque' => $item['estoque'],
                'status_e' => 1,
                'status_obs_e' => 2,
                'autorizado' => $item['autorizado'],
            );
        } else {
            $groups[$key] = array(
                'codProposta' => $item['codProposta'],
                'codCliente' => $item['codCliente'],
                'entrega' => $item['entrega'],
                'qtde' => $groups[$key]['qtde'] + $item['qtde'],
                'mes' => $item['mes'],
                'mes_entrega' => $item['mes_entrega'],
                'ano' => $item['ano'],
                'estoque' => $item['estoque'],
                'status_e' => 1,
                'status_obs_e' => 2,
                'autorizado' => $item['autorizado'],
            );
        }
    }
    return $groups;
}
```